# Exponential replication of object

Tags: modifiers, objects, animation-nodes, instances

I'm trying to figure out how I can create an array of objects where each instance has an increasing number instances of that starting object.
A simple example:

1 cube 
2 cubes (to the right and stacked on top of eachother)
4 cubes (to the right of the 2 cubes and also stacked)
8 cubes 
16 cubes
and so on...

This continues for x number of instances.

I tried the array modifier with very little luck and also the replicator in animation nodes.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to some help from Jaque Luke (see this post here [Animation Nodes: How to unzip a list](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60766/animation-nodes-how-to-unzip-a-list)) I found a slightly different solution: I'm using the Object Instancer, which you can now feed in any Object you like, and first compose a list of target positioning vectors. Then I loop over the list length of those vectors and apply the locations to each Object Instance. A Blend file is here:

[image]

The starting point takes a few parameters, allowing you to choose what the distances should be, and also on which column to start. Also, you can pick the object from here:

[image: start]

Next, I'm generating the Columns, and also calculate how many rows each column will have:

[image: step 2]

I feed that into an extra Sub-Loop to generate the Vectors finally for each column:

[image: column vectors]

This however generates a list of a bunch of vectors lists:

[image: lists]

To decompose them, I've used the Expression node in this setup:

[image: decompose]

Now, all I needed to do was to get the length of this list and use it as a number of iterations for the loop. I loop over each list item (each item is a vector, i.e. the new location of the object), and set the vector accordingly:

[image: final loop]

and the result is:

[image: result]

Comment: Hi and sorry for my late reply. (too busy lately)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I understand the overall concept of how you did it. But I'm still trying to understand the details of it. Regardless, this  helps a lot! Thanks for the effort! Cheers

Comment: Got it! Nice out-of-the-box thinking!

Answer (score 3):

I tried to find a workaround for this problem,I found one which is not really good,but should be working fine,Using animation nodes.

The Idea is to generate a set of points in the first quadrant,then exclude all the points that are inside of the parabola (x^2 curve) using a loop with a condition.
Then there is the loop that put the object it the list that is left with us.

Here is the node tree:

[image: Node tree]

And here is the result:

[image: Results]